# using php to resize images from url before saving to server

Tags: php, image, resize

i'm trying to resize an image and save it to my server. i figured out how to save the image from a URL, but then I want to resize the image and save it in the exact same location. this is the script i'm currently using. it's saving the image but the resize isn't working.

```
$cover = $_POST['cover'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));


$url = $cover;
$save_name = $artist."_".$title.".jpg";
$save_name = str_replace(' ','',$save_name);
$save_directory = $_ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/albums/images/art/";

if(is_writable($save_directory)) {
    file_put_contents($save_directory . $save_name, file_get_contents($url));
} else {
     exit("Failed to write to directory ".$save_directory);
}

$location = "http://www.MYURL.com/albums/images/art/".$save_name;
$sql = "INSERT INTO albums (artist, title, date, cover) VALUES ('".$artist."', '".$title."', '".$date."', '".$location."')";
mysql_query($sql);



include("resize-class.php");
$resizeObj = new resize($location);
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 150, 'exact');
$resizeObj -> saveImage($save_name, 100);
```

i'm using [resize-class.php](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/) which i thought would make things easy but it's not working. i think i might be confusing my resize path or output path but i'm not entirely sure. any tips would be really helpful

Comment: ok, but you use the save_name, it only have the name, you dont point where is the folder.
File.jpg (what you use)
/home/user/images/destiny/File.jpg
What you should use.
Check if the file is not saved in another place

Comment: Try this too check if `gd` is installed `if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump(gd_info()); echo "</pre>";
 }`

Comment: ["GD Version"]=>
  string(27) "bundled (2.0.34 compatible)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because you're trying to save the image to a URL, instead of a relative or absolute path on the server. If you look at your code, the location is set as an HTTP path.

Comment: i don't know? how can i check. i'm using bluehost

Comment: Here's something I found that might help you check: http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?650-GD-Library!!!-Most-important-for-some-scripts-have-we-got-that

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: anytime you have to ask OP a question it is not an answer.

Comment: I removed the question portion. That being said, I DID provide an answer directly below. No need for snark.

Comment: what am i doing wrong? i'm loading the full image from the server with `http://...../theimage.jpg` and then setting using `$_ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/albums/images/art/` in the `saveImage()` function but it's still not working

Comment: So the resize is working, but my images aren't going into the correct spot.

Comment: I got it! It was an issue with the path...